# Sometimes, the review page doesn't show the original suggested edit

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

With [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1227127), the review page doesn't show the correct question body with the original suggested edit; the question body shown is the last revision of the post instead. The suggestion *only* shows the title change suggested:

> [image: screenshot]

That is evident from the [revision page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14009272/revisions).

> [image: screenshot]

Note that the body was edited by me after I clicked the 'improve' button, the suggested edit page now shows the body as revised by me instead of [what was there before my revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14009272/3).

I improved the edit because it was clear the body needed improving too, but if now somebody looks at the suggested edit page, they could wonder why the edit was rejected via the 'improve' button, when the only possible edit was changing the first letter in the title.

The same doesn't happen for [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1224658), though.

Comment: It's a bug report.

Comment: The suggested edit you link to *only* edits the title. Are you certain you are looking at the correct suggestion, or at your edit instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters The first screenshot is from the review page showing the suggested edit; the second one is from the revision page for the edited question. It's correct: The suggested edit is editing the title. It's the question text that is not what who suggested the edit saw. I know it, as it was me to edited out, for example, the second question mark. I did it by clicking on the "improve" button, which means I did it after that user suggested his edit.

Comment: Right, I see what you mean. On the now-rejected edit suggestion the question *body* shown is the current revision, instead of using the revision of the question body used at the time of the suggestion. Got it, that'd indeed be a bug in my eyes too.

Comment: Fun! The `source` links on the revision page don't work for me.. nothing happens, just `loading...` being displayed. Fishy!

Comment: @MartijnPieters It works for me for revision #1, #2, and #4 (the ones with a "source" link).

Comment: Questions have a title and a body; my guess is that the code showing the suggestion doesn't do the right thing for the body because the previous edit was also only editing the title. Glad the source link works for you.